# Google Map took div on my web page but not displays

Tags: jsp, jquery-mobile, servlets

I am building a project in NetBeans (Servlet/JSP/mobile jQuery) where I have to display last location of vehicle on Google Map. Now, I am displaying map on button click which will show on another JSP page.

What is happening the map division took place but not display the map and if I will run that page alone as run file on right click it shows Google Map. Also if remove jQuery for mobile and run the project without using mobile jQuery it runs correctly.

Anyone can explain me why it is happening?

JSP page where I want to display my map is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
<script>
    $("div:jqmData(role='page'):last").bind('pageinit', function() {
            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                    initialize(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                });
            }
        }); `
            function initializemap()
            {
                var mapProp123 = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map123 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap123")
                        , mapProp123);
            }

        </script>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

                <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
                <input type="button" value="get map" onclick="initializemap();">
                <div id="googleMap123" style="height: 300px;"></div>
            </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this does not included in code...$("div:jqmData(role='page'):last").bind('pageinit', function() {
            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                    initialize(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                });
            }
        }); `

Answer (score 0):

Put your content in a page:

```
<div id="firstPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
        <input type="button" value="get map" onclick="initializemap();">
        <div id="googleMap123" style="height: 300px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```